# css "onclick" pseudo effect issues

Tags: css

Using the exact same CSS,

the onclick pseudo effect works fine with this code on one page of same site:

```
<a data-url="#" class="btn btn-share referral_button">Button Text</a>
```

(but admittedly it is on a different page with different divs)

but not on another page, where the code is:

```
<a data-url="#" class="btn btn-share referral_button" onclick="javascript:$find('ABC').set_activeTabIndex(3);">Button Text</a>
```

instead of behaving as it should it shrinks when clicked - and sort of reverts to how it would look without any css styled - or at least not the correct css styling

I initially thought it was something to do with the onclick="javascript... stuff somehow clashing/over-riding and affecting the CSS from performing how it should but *** EDIT**  it can't be this because I just removed the whole onclick section and the problem still existed :( **

so it must be something else..

the relevant CSS is here: sorry it's long and probably bloated. the most relevant stuff i believe is at the bottom...

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1N7YQ5YuvY6DJn8-nr4sinx4LY7WOS88eErpRHe4IE_g/pub

Comment: What is the actual expected behaviour? Can you provide an example of it working or broken in a jsfidle (http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: the example that doesn't work is a live page on live site so not sure if i should share it here but what differs is that when you click the button it shrinks and changes styling and because it shrinks it effects all the content below it.. it's driving me nuts!

Comment: It is hard to help you if we can not see the context of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as how its an invalid syntax, I would say remove the " \9" from all of your `:active` and `.active` statements

Like below:
`.btn.active{background-color:#cccccc \9;}`

EDIT: Furthermore, (not really relevant to the answer)
Your CSS is a pretty hot mess. (No offence)
You can easily clean that up and make it a lot more manageable.
Plus, it could just be my tired eyes, but it seams like half of it is just repeating and/or overwriting the other half (which goes back to cleaning it up and making it manageable).

Honestly though, your the one working on it, so its as long as you can read it and use it. To each their own. I prefer my CSS quite readable in a dev environment.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. done. removed them. but doesn't fix the problem. have updated the google doc css code link above with corrected css.

Comment: oh wow, so maybe I shouldn't have removed them. anyway, i don't think they have anything to do with the problem. to me, it's something to do with the javascript that is being triggered by the onclick event

Comment: @Fabrício Matté Ah. Gotcha. I was never into the various hacks for IE's shenanigans. I just tried to make my stuff cross-browser compliant with out them. Thanks for the information about that though!

Comment: Seems I'm stuck...

I appreciate your advice to clean up the CSS but what doesn't make sense is why the CSS as it is works fine now on one page on site... This is driving me nuts. I thought I defined the problem clearly enough but somehow not many people have viewed let alone attempted to help. Thanks for your input anyway.

Comment: I'm finally getting results going back to the CSS and not really cleaning it up per se but tweaking it.. and getting very good results.. so it seems it is not a clash with other CSS code but somehow just strange how the CSS code worked on one page but not on another without this tweaking. I know, my explanation is terrible and I am clearly showing my poor coding skills to the world, but.. hey at least i've got it working, worked it out one way or another :)

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious suggestion is there is something on this mysterious "Other" page, that is overriding the style.

Use a tool like Firebug for Firefox to inspect the elements and its' styles this may give you a hint as to what is overiding the behaviour you are expecting.

Also check that the CSS is the same on both pages if you are not using a common CSS file.

Read up on [CSS Specificity](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=css%20specificity%20rules&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr), which is could  be the root cause of you problem. This could help explain why style `b` is overiding style `a`.

It boils down to some difference on the two pages.

Comment: Thanks Jon, this is helpful. It seems that other css styles on the "other" page are over-riding when I click on the button. I will try to investigate as best I can. I don't use Firefox but am using Chrome - the debug tool that comes up when you right click and choose "inspect element"

Comment: Using Chrome hit "f12" to bring up a similar tool to firebug. But I prefer the firefox/firebug combination, to me it is more powerful. If you are serious about this web developing/design thing you should be running as many browsers as possible. At least Firefox, Chrome, IE (if on windows), Safari (on a Mac).Cross browser issues are still very much alive

Comment: the relevant CSS attribute is :active or .active as I understand (that relates to the mouse being clicked on the element) so am I looking for other similar CSS attributes on the page that have a higher specificity value and therefore are somehow over-riding?

Comment: `.active is` a class assigned to an element, e.g: `class="active"`, `:active` is the style applied when the element is active/clicked. You currently have three clases applied to the button. The are `:active` states defined for just about all of them. These will all be triggered, Specifity and Cascading rules will determine how they are applied.

Comment: what I mean is, when looking through other CSS code to find the CSS which is clashing/over-riding (the page with the problem has additional CSS).. so as I understand I am looking for other elements in the additional CSS that also specify the :active style right? because to my thinking, it must be something that has higher specificity/cascading rule power over the same :active style that is being over-ridden..  sorry, I know I am not good at explaining it.. I am really trying here though. Spent a whole day on this!

Comment: i've just learnt that the amount the button shrinks in size is a percentage of the original size i.e. it's not shrinking to a fixed size. interesting. still can't find any other CSS code that would seem to have specificity or cascading power over it. i'll keep going even though common sense says to give up.

Comment: I'm finally getting results going back to the CSS and not really cleaning it up per se but tweaking it.. and getting very good results.. so it seems it is not a clash with other CSS code but somehow just strange how the CSS code worked on one page but not on another without this tweaking. I know, my explanation is terrible and I am clearly showing my poor coding skills to the world, but.. hey at least i've got it working, worked it out one way or another :)